# Add a new item in a SQL Server database with wcf web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wcf

I'm using WCF to show data from a SQL Server database in a WPF application with grid.

How can I add a new row to the database using WCF web services?

My service code

```
public class abalaseService : DataService<eshop2Entities>
    {

        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("tblProduct", EntitySetRights.All);
        }
    }
```

In XAML

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,16,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding}">
            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu AllowDrop="True" />
            </Grid.ContextMenu>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Ενεργό:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Active, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Margin="3" Name="activeCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="Id Προμηθευτή:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="brandIdTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=BrandId, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Id Κατηγορίας:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="categoryIdTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Περιγραφή:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="descriptionTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Id:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="idTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Όνομα:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="nameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Τιμή Αγοράς:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="purchasePriceTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=PurchasePrice, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Απόθεμα:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="quantityTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Τιμή Πώλησης:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="salePriceTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SalePrice, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
        </Grid>
```

I'd like a clear grid that user can fill and save the record to db (add a new product)

How can I do that?

I'm new to WCF and web services

Comment: Are you currently able to pass data across WCF?  If so, what data are you currently passing successfully?

Comment: I'm able to retrieve data across wcf. The code above returns a grid with details for a product from tblProduct table in database. I'd like to add a new product. I don't know if any other aproach exists!